# AVD manager in android studio not opening

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

my AVD manager in Android studio isn't opening even the icon is gray and the android in tools is unavailable(not there) 
I'm running Android studio 3.0 on windows 10

Comment: Do you get any toast/popup(error message)?

Comment: no i cant even click on it from the find action

Comment: and the android in tools bar isnt shown